# sum (not count cases) of a numeric vector based on relative value

Tags: r, sum, conditional-statements

```
df<-data.frame(a=1:100)
sum(df$a>50)
[1] 50
```

The answer I am looking for is the sum of 51+52...100.  I tried searching but only finding poor questions/ratings or leads to Excel sumif.  Thanks

Comment: `a > 50` returns a logical, ie, yes/no `TRUE`/`FALSE`. Since R is vectorized, you get a vector of logicals. `TRUE` can be coerced to 1 and `FALSE` to 0, so your sum is `1 + 1 + ... + 1` = 50. You would need to subset the vector first (`a[51:100]`) and then sum that.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
sum(subset(df,a>50))
```

Answer (score 1):

Unsing the condition in the "address brackets" works without a subset.

```
sum( df[ df$a>50, ])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that there are a few things going on with your question.  I'll try to answer them one at a time:

You created a data.frame, but then only used it for the vector.  Let's try to create just one variable to answer your question:

```
a = 1:50
```

You created data where each variable (e.g. x[10]) is equal to the value of the index (e.g. 10).  As we'll see below, this can lead to some confusion because there are multiple ways to index in R.  So let's use this:

```
set.seed(0)
a = sample(100, n=50)
```

In your question, you call sum(a > 50).  First you should try to understand what a > 50 returns.  It might not be what you think!

```
a > 50
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

That is, `a > 50`  returns the result of applying the (logical) test "greater than 50?" to *each* value in the vector a.  This is the "vectorization" that you often hear about in R.

Note that in R, you can put a boolean (logical) vector as a subscript to a vector.  It will only return the elements which are TRUE:

```
a[a > 50]
[1] 90 56 88 85 96 61 58 60 66 87 82 63 74 51 62 86 69 54 77 92 81 64 83 91
```

Of course, these values can then be fed to `sum`

```
sum(a[a > 50])
[1] 1776
```

At some point this will become second nature to you.  I recommend reading John Cook's great blog post: [Five Kinds of Subscripts in R](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/10/23/five-kinds-of-r-language-subscripts/) - it will help you to be able to answer all sorts of related questions.